# build map dynamically in slam,not using static map

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have checked several tutorial,examples,and questions.
I also have wrote : robot_setup_laser,robot_setup_tf,robot_setup_odometry,robot_setup_base packages,and launch file.
The laser data is real.
tf,odom's data are now fake,latter will be true.

My question is how to navigation by the map which dynamically generate,
not by static map generated by gmapping?

Which portion should I load? map_server? gmapping?

Which configuration should I set?
Now I only know in

1. global_costmap_params.yaml -> static_map: false , rolling_window: true

I have already change the file in navigation_tutorials/navigation_stage/move_base_config

2. 

Am I right?
Is there any location I lose?
Thank you~~

My launch file is

```
  <launch>
  
    <master auto="start"/>
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>  
  
    <node pkg="robot_setup_laser" type="laser" name="sensor_node_name" output="screen">
      <param name="sensor_param" value="param_value" />
    </node>
  
    <node pkg="robot_setup_odometry" type="odometry" name="odom_node" output="screen">
      <param name="odom_param" value="param_value" />
    </node>
  
    <node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="tf_broadcaster" name="transform_configuration_name" output="screen">
      <param name="transform_configuration_param" value="param_value" />
    </node>
  
    <node pkg="robot_setup_base" type="base" name="base" output="screen">
      <param name="transform_configuration_param" value="param_value" />
    </node>
  
    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
        <!--remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/-->
        <!--param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/-->
        <param name="map_update_interval" value="2.0"/>
        <param name="maxUrange" value="6.0"/>
        <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
        <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
        <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
        <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
        <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
        <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
        <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
        <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
        <param name="srr" value="0.01"/>
        <param name="srt" value="0.02"/>
        <param name="str" value="0.01"/>
        <param name="stt" value="0.02"/>
        <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.25"/>     <!-- param name="linearUpdate" value="0.5"/-->
        <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.262"/>   <!--param name="angularUpdate" value="0.436"/-->
        <param name="temporalUpdate" value="-1.0"/>
        <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
        <param name="particles" value="300"/>
        <param name="xmin" value="-50.0"/>
        <param name="ymin" value="-50.0"/>
        <param name="xmax" value="50.0"/>
        <param name="ymax" value="50.0"/>
        <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
        <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
        <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
        <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
        <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
    </node>
  
    <!--- Run AMCL -->
    <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" />
  
    <node pkg="stage" type="stageros" name="stageros" args="$(optenv ROS_STAGE_GRAPHICS -g) $(find       navigation_stage)/stage_config/worlds/willow-pr2-multi.world" respawn="false">
      <param name="base_watchdog_timeout" value="0.2"/>
    </node>
  
    <!-- Throttle the voxel grid that is being published for rviz -->
    <node ns="move_base_node/local_costmap" name="voxel_grid_throttle" pkg="topic_tools" type="throttle" args="messages       voxel_grid 3.0 voxel_grid_throttled" />
  
    <group ns="robot_0">
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_0" />
      <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base_node" output="screen">
        <remap from="map" to="/map" />
        <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0" />
        <rosparam file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load"       ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load"       ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find navigation_stage)/move_base_config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
      </node>
  
        <node pkg="fake_localization" type="fake_localization" name="fake_localization" respawn="false">
      </node>
    </group>
    
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find navigation_stage)/multi_robot.vcg" />
  
  </launch>
```

And the output is

```
  [ WARN] [1307435305.622374073]: Request for map failed; trying again...
  [ INFO] [1307435305.883163698]: URG: array[387]=0.575000
  
  [ WARN] [1307435306.130109962]: Request for map failed; trying again...
  [ INFO] [1307435306.203036936]: publish odom : x=0.583510,y=-0.386810
  
  [ WARN] [1307435306.635515320]: Request for map failed; trying again...
  [ INFO] [1307435306.873185418]: URG: array[387]=0.573000
  
  [ WARN] [1307435307.141589966]: Request for map failed; trying again...
  [ INFO] [1307435307.202924911]: publish odom : x=0.719206,y=-0.426622
  
  [ WARN] [1307435307.647295991]: Request for map failed; trying again...
  [ INFO] [1307435307.873182415]: URG: array[387]=0.575000
  
  [ WARN] [1307435308.153213704]: Request for map failed; trying again...
  [ INFO] [1307435308.202996708]: publish odom : x=0.858210,y=-0.452691
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10180/build-map-dynamically-in-slam,not-using-static-map/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's some weird stuff going on in your launch files, particularly with the inclusion of the "fake_localization" node. Have you tried running the `move_base_gmapping_5cm.launch` launch file in the [navigation_stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_stage) package? If that works for you, you'd just want to replace the `rosstage` node with your custom odometry and laser scan.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-08**:
The move_base_amcl* launch files are not supposed to use a dynamic map. Only the move_base_gmapping* launch files are supposed to use slam.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-06-08**:
Thank you for this information. I have a question that why move_base_amcl_5cm.launch use static map (willow-full-0.05.pgm) in map_server node? If I want to build map during slam not using static map. Should I also change move_base_amcl_5cm.launch ?